# http service is undefined even when it is initialized inside constructor. angular js 1.5 and typescript combination

Tags: angularjs, typescript

http service is undefined even when it is initialized inside constructor. angular js 1.5 and typescript combination.

```
Export class mypowerfullCtrl
{
   _http: ng.IHttpService;

    //defined _http variable

     constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService)
     {
          this._http=$http;
     } 

      this._http.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites").success(function 

     (data, status) {

          console.log(data);

      });
}
```

What ever I do `this._http` remains undefined.

Why is this happening?

Even if I place `this._http` inside constructor after assigning value. It remains undefined. Funny part this does not happen with `$scope`. It gets value on passed through constructor and asssigned value to global variable.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you show the entire class or at least where exactly you have the `this._http.get(...)` piece of code and how that gets called

Comment: You had accessed `this._http` before constructor setting a value of `_http`

Comment: Can you please show the full file?

Comment: Btw you can just use `this.$http` anywhere inside your class. You don't have to create a new variable, because the way you define the `$http` parameter in your constructor, it will automatically create a private member with the same name

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
Export class mypowerfullCtrl
{
    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
    }

    // Create a function you will call
    get() {
        this._http.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites")
            .success(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
}
```